# Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : Any]' with an index of type 'UIImagePickerController.InfoKey'

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm using [Apple's Swift iOS Tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/WorkWithViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH6-SW1). Which is throwing an error,

> Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : Any]' with an index of type 'UIImagePickerController.InfoKey'

The function they defined is below.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    // The info dictionary may contain multiple representations of the image. You want to use the original.
    guard let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage else {
        fatalError("Expected a dictionary containing an image, but was provided the following: \(info)")
    }

    // Set photoImageView to display the selected image.
    photoImageView.image = selectedImage

    // Dismiss the picker.
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I'm using Xcode Version 10.0 beta 3, which includes Swift 4.2.

I'd like to understand how to traverse the docs to understand what might have changed or broken.

Comment: I noticed that another line later in this tutorial also threw an error - `button.addTarget(self, action:  #selector(RatingControl.ratingButtonTapped(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)`. In case others have the same issue -- I was able to fix it by adding `@objcMembers` right at the beginning of the class line, like this: `@objcMembers class RatingControl: UIStackView {`. See https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/how-to-fix-argument-of-selector-refers-to-instance-method-that-is-not-exposed-to-objective-c

Answer (score 118):

The signature of the method has changed in Swift 4.2

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, 
  didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any])
```

and you have to write

```
guard let selectedImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage else {
    fatalError("Expected a dictionary containing an image, but was provided the following: \(info)")
}
```

You can figure out such terminology changes yourself by reading the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontrollerdelegate/1619126-imagepickercontroller?changes=latest_minor) or by commenting out the entire method, retype the first few characters and use code completion.

Comment: Great, it has cleared off the errors in the IDE. Like the OP I just began doing iOS and following the same tutorial.

Comment: Does anyone get an error like this "'UIImage?' is not convertible to 'UIImage'" at "as?" ?

Answer (score 27):

I'm following also the same tutorial, the updated code looks like this:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

    // The info dictionary may contain multiple representations of the image. You want to use the original.
    guard let selectedImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage else {
        fatalError("Expected a dictionary containing an image, but was provided the following: \(info)")
    }

    // Set photoImageView to display the selected image.
    photoImageView.image = selectedImage

    // Dismiss the picker.
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 20):

### Swift 5

In latest version of swift 4 or 5 the delegate method is given below, it should work

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    // Code here
}
```

And use,

```
guard let selectedImage = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage else {

}



func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    guard let selectedImage = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage else {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Use like this,

```
guard let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage.rawValue] as? UIImage else {
        fatalError("Expected a dictionary containing an image, but was provided the following: \(info)")
}
```

Answer (score 8):

In  Swift 4 and 5  like so:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

    guard let selectedImage = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage else {
        fatalError("Expected a dictionary containing an image, but was provided the following: \(info)")
    }

    self.myImageView.image = selectedImage

    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: There is no difference between Swift 4 and 5

Answer (score 3):

I am also following the tutorial. It is working after changing as below.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

    // The info dictionary may contain multiple representations of the image. You want to use the original.
    guard let selectedImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage
        else {
        fatalError("Expected a dictionary containing an image, but was provided the following: \(info)")
    }

    // Set photoImageView to display the selected image.
    photoImageView.image = selectedImage

    // Dismiss the picker.
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I am using XCode 11 and Swift 5.

Answer (score 1):

Method has been changed a little bit in Swift 4.2.

First initialise these two variables:

```
var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
var pickedImageProduct = UIImage()

extension yourViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate{
//create an IBAction to access Camera
    @IBAction func accessCameraBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerController.SourceType.camera
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
//create an IBAction to access Gallery
    @IBAction func accessGalleryBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerController.SourceType.photoLibrary
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
//Final step put this Delegate    
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,
                               didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

        guard let selectedImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage else {
           Print("Error: \(info)")
        }

            pickedImageProduct = selectedImage

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
     }
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Comment: The method has been changed by sooner, I think in `4.0` or maybe even sooner.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 4.2 you can write the function as:

```
    func photoLib()
    {
        //opens Photo Library, call the function in a @IBAction func
        let myPickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        myPickerController.delegate = self;
        myPickerController.sourceType = 
        UIImagePickerController.SourceType.photoLibrary
        myPickerController.allowsEditing = true
        present(myPickerController, animated: true)
    }


    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, 
    didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true)

    guard let image = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage else {
        print("No image found")
        photoLabel.text = "Photo Not Found"
        return
    }
}
```